# Why can I pass "if largest is None or largest < num:" but not "if largest < num:"

Tags: python

When I try to pass " but not "if largest < num:" I get "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'". Which means I can't compare NoneType and integers. But wouldn't that still be the case for "if largest is None or largest < num:"?

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        try:
            num = int(num)  
            if largest is None or largest < num:
                largest = num
            if smallest is None or smallest > num:
                smallest = num 
        except:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: `or` short-circuits; if the left side is true the whole expression is definitionally true already (by boolean logic rules), so the right side isn't even evaluated.

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer. Please check your environment again. Do you save your code already.

Comment: @ramwin the question is about why it works. OP expects it not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain, here's an example:

```
if True or (1 < None):
    print('yep')

if 1 < None:
    print('this does not print, because the above throws an exception')
```

Prints `yep` but then `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`.

The reason this happens is, as @shadowranger indicated in comments, that logical operators like `or` and `and` short-circuit.

For `or`, that means that when evaluating `P or Q`, if `P` evaluates to `True`, there's no need to evaluate `Q`, since the expression will be `True` regardless - so Python doesn't.

Similarly, for `and`, it means than when evaluating `P and Q`, if `P` evaluates to `False`, there's no need to evaluate `Q`, since the expression will be `False` regardless - so Python doesn't.

So, you can see why this won't throw an exception, since the offending code never gets executed:

```
if True or (1 < None):
    print('yep')
```